# creating a stored procedure that enables/disables(depending on passed parameter) all foreign keys (DB2, V10.5)

Tags: sql, linux, stored-procedures, db2, constraints

Names of the foreign keys should be get from the system tables dynamicaly.
That's what I've got for now: 
"select 'alter table ' ||tabname||' alter foreign key ' ||constname||' not enforced;' from syscat.references"

This following code outputs such queries:

```
alter table ADDRESS alter foreign key SQL161110091657410 not enforced;
alter table ADDRESS alter foreign key SQL161110091748740 not enforced;
alter table CLIENT alter foreign key SQL161110092705870 not enforced;
alter table CLINIC alter foreign key SQL161110091917520 not enforced;
alter table DOCTOR alter foreign key SQL161110091133120 not enforced;
....
```

Now I need to execute these queries in stored procedure (depending on passed parameter). The following code is incorrect, I attach it just to illustrate the problem:

```
db2 "create procedure fk_switch (sw IN varchar(3)) 
   begin
   declare var1 varchar(100), var2 varchar(100)
   if sw='off' then @var1=select 'alter table ' ||tabname||' alter foreign key ' ||constname||' not enforced;' from syscat.references
   execute @var1
   elseif sw='on' then @var=select 'alter table ' ||tabname||' alter foreign key ' ||constname||' enforced;' from syscat.references
   execute @var2
   end if;
   end;"
```

How do I write the results of selects into variables? can I execute them within procedure? or maybe there is another solution?

And yes, I know, that it can be solved by using bash, but my task is to create a stored procedure:)

Please share some links about db2 stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you could compose the SQL string (as "var1") within your procedure and would be able to use `EXECUTE` to run it, but not successfully. It is not possible to solve your problem with a stored procedure.

By taking a look at what [SQL statements are supported in SQL routines](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.routines.doc/doc/r0020478.html) (functions, procedures) you will notice that `ALTER TABLE` is not supported.

Comment: You can find several examples of how to use Execute in SQL PL in db2unit: https://github.com/angoca/db2unit/blob/master/src/main/sql-pl/04-Body.sql